# Does hosting your website on AWS or other cloud services provide added security for authentication when logging in a user?

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, cloud

So, I have been reading up on cloud and feel it does not provide any added security for login authentication but I may be wrong. I feel that the hackers can crack the faulty code/security features on the login page and hack (such as rapid fire login attempts). It may be secure to store the database  that has the password with AWS as it will be difficult to crack into but not the database.

Comment: login authentication to what?  Your websites functionality?  Or the actual administration of your services?  If you're talking about your own websites functionality, then no there is no additional added security, it's up to you to harden authentication.

Comment: Yeah, my question referred to security for website functionality. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no intrinsic benefits to authentication present in cloud environments. Authentication is handled by your application and wether or not it is secure depends solely on your business logic.